# Define a projection for LAScatalog chunks using the lidR package in R

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, lidr, grid-metrics

Using `lidR::grid_metrics` with a `LAScatalog` is it possible to use a second projection for the processing "chunks" such that the resulting raster cells align with a raster image (sentinel 2)? I know there is the realignment option for a catalog to change the origin of the chunks, but it seems I need to take it a step further. I want to avoid re-projecting the imagery which would result in information loss. I could always re-project the LAS data, but this is undesireable as well. The EPSG of the LAS tiles is 2992 (Oregon Lambert Feet) and the imagery is 32610 (UTM 10N).

Comment: Have you considered computing the metrics in the CRS of the point cloud and reproject the resulting raster in the CRS of the sentinel images at the end of the computation?

Comment: Either way there is a loss of information during the reprojection. It would be interesting to test both to see if the difference is significant, but I suspect reprojecting the imagery would be preferable.

Comment: Looking at the source for `readLAS` it appears that it operates on extents in native coordinates, rather than arbitrary geometry, which would be required for my question. Extents make for efficient IO, so this make sense.

Comment: So, you don't want to reproject the point cloud, you don't want to reproject the raster of metrics and you don't want to reproject the imagery. You will have to reproject something somehow to match the CRS. It is not clear what you're asking

Comment: To be concise, can the LAScatalog chunk tessellations be built using a coordinate system other than the source LAS tiles? However, after further consideration I think this would less efficient than simply reprojecting the LAS data since it requires something more complex than a simple extent based extraction. I'll move on the plan B.

Comment: No it is not possible and even if it were this would not solve your problem. I think that reprojecting the entire point cloud is the unique lossless option.